# Should I write a tool to re-export modules within my application?

Tags: angular, typescript

In a TypeScript application of any size, you will likely end up with a LOT of modules. In my experience so far, this has resulted in import statements which look like: `import { x } from '../../../y/z'`

Angular 2 has a nice way around this: exporting all the modules within a folder via an `index.ts / index.d.ts` file.

I've begun using these myself as it cleans up the imports enough to make it worthwhile. What I have been curious about is creating a tool to automatically scrape the file names from the directory and drop a `.d.ts` file in there. I've seen nothing else on the web to suggest this is something anyone has tried.

So, my question is this: is there a technical limitation to writing something like this that I haven't figured out yet?

My thinking for the tool would be that the user would drop an `index.ts` file in and if the tool finds it, it will ensure the exports are all updated to point to any exported modules from that directory downwards.

I will begin experimenting with this in the next few days but wanted some more experienced input before I do - if possible.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This does not really answer your question, but it might help in deciding whether to build a tool like that.

I am quite new to Angular 2, but the following has helped me avoid the "../../../" type of import statements.

```
/app
    /core
         /network
         /storage
         index.ts
         core.module.ts
    /resources
              /user
              resources.module.ts
    /shared
           /utilities
           shared.module.ts
```

If we take the core directory as an example:

Within core.module.ts I would have imports like:

```
import { StorageService } from './storage/storage.service';
```

And within app/core/index.ts I would make a barrel to export the services (for instance) that components would use:

```
export * from './network/client.service';
export * from './storage/storage.service';
```

Then from any other place (such as use user service in app/resources/user) I would import what I need as

```
import { ClientService, StorageService } from 'app/core';
```

The idea is basically to use relative imports only to deeper levels of the current module and "absolute" imports for imports from sibling directories (modules).

So far this has kept my imports clean and easy to read and reason about. I know there is an issue with the order of barrel imports, but I am not sure about the details of it.

Note: This is with Webpack and Typescript configured to use "absolute" path imports.